# Regarding the repetion of block for limited times

Tags: c#, loops, one-time-password

I had implemented a random function to generate random OTPs and I wanted the user to enter the incorrect OTP for at most 3times. If the user fails to enter the correct OTP for the fourth consecutive attempt the loop must be terminated. I am unable to sort it out

I've tried this in visual studio and facing this issue of a continuous loop.

```
string otps = otp.getOtp(); // Get Random otp from getotp method below
Console.WriteLine("OTP Generated:{0}", otps);
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter OTP");
    string userotp = Console.ReadLine(); // Read OTP
    if (userotp == otps) // If OTP is valid
    {
        val1 = false;
        return totalprice;
    }
    else
    {
        while (i >= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect OTP");                                          
            Console.WriteLine("Please Re Enter your Password {0} attempts left", i);
            if(userotp != otps)
            {
                val1 = true;
                i--;
            }                                            
            else if (userotp == otps) // If OTP is valid
            {
                val1 = false;
                return totalprice;
            }
        }
     }
 } while (val1);
```

---

```
**************************************  WELCOME TO WALMART  ************************************************
Enter Product Name:
sgf
Enter Product Price:
4356
-----------------------------
 Total price :4356
 -----------------------------
Please Enter Payment option:
 1.CreditCard
 2.NetBanking
 3.Paytm
1
Enter Credit Card Number:
23456789
ReEnter Credit Card Number:
23456789
Enter your Name
Chakradhar
Please Enter CVV Number
***OTP Generated:444
Enter OTP
555
Incorrect OTP
Please Re Enter your Password 3 attempts left
//I NEED TO CALL THE ENTER OTP HERE//
Incorrect OTP
Please Re-Enter your Password 2 attempts left
Incorrect OTP
Please Re-Enter your Password 1 attempts left
Enter OTP
```

[image: THE ERROR WAS CLEARLY SHOWN IN THE PICTURE BELOW]

Comment: what's an OTP? Why do I need to know what an OTP is to understand your question? What is your actual _question_? Please improve your post. Read [ask] to understand how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. Make sure you also read [mcve], so you know what kind of code to post. Explain exactly what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and _precisely_ what it is you need help figuring out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note is that setting `val1` to terminate the loop and returning doesn't make sense. You are overcomplicating this simple problem. I would suggest a simpler approach:

```
string otp=otp.getOtp();
string input;
int attemptsLeft=3;

while(attemptsLeft>0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter OTP");
   input=Console.ReadLine();
   if(input==otp)
       return totalprice;
   else
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect OTP");  
        Console.WriteLine("Please Re Enter your Password {0} attempts left", attemptsLeft--);
   }

}
//Handle three unsuccessful attempts
```